# Remove header row in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Can anyone tell me how to remove the header row in a tkinter Treeview?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

NewTree= ttk.Treeview(root)
NewTree.pack()
NewTree.heading("#0", text="How to remove this row?")
NewTree.insert("", "0", 'item1',text='Item number 1')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `show` option to only show the tree and not the heading:

```
NewTree = ttk.Treeview(root, show="tree")
```

---

**Relevant documentation**

From [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html):

> show
>
> A list containing zero or more of the following values, specifying which elements of the tree to display.
>
> - tree: display tree labels in column #0.
> - headings: display the heading row.
>
> The default is “tree headings”, i.e., show all elements.
>
> **Note**: Column #0 always refers to the tree column, even if show=”tree” is not specified.

From the [New Mexico Tech Tkinter reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530090350/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html):

> show
>
> To suppress the labels at the top of each column, specify `show='tree'`. The default is to show the column labels.

From [TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html):

> You can optionally hide one or both of the column headings or the tree itself (leaving just the columns) using the `show` widget configuration option (default is `"tree headings"` to show both).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. If you haven't already, please read the help page on [what you can do when you get an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks, such an easy thing to overlook.